# No end point for service interface! "Error"

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jco

I'm getting No end point and attachment support error while I'm trying to reach my webservice.

I can make the authorization but then I can not be able to get to the webservice because of this "No end point" error.

```
Console:
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.NoEndpoint

 faultSubcode: 

faultString: No endpoint <------------

 faultActor: 

 faultNode: 

 faultDetail: 

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}exceptionName:org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:No endpoint  <--------------

    at functions.rfc.sap.document.sap_com.Zws001_BindingStub.ZF_GET_CUSTOMERS(Zws001_BindingStub.java:414)
    at test.test1.main(test1.java:23)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:logosi3

No endpoint
    at functions.rfc.sap.document.sap_com.Zws001_BindingStub.ZF_GET_CUSTOMERS(Zws001_BindingStub.java:414)
    at test.test1.main(test1.java:23)
```

Comment: The *endpoint* is an URL, have you tried to talk with your service through soupUI already (I guess it's SOAP.. you're using axis)

Comment: I'm using SOAP yes. Can you please tell me how can i talk with the service via soupUI?

Comment: .. err, sorry, typo, it's [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Follow the link, install the tool, there should be some tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by calling the service using locator class rather than directly loading stub class -

```
GlobalWeatherLocator locator = new GlobalWeatherLocator();
        String cityName = "delhi";
        String countryName = "India";
        String data = locator.getGlobalWeatherSoap().getWeather(cityName, countryName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by calling the Locator file first and then calling the method which you want to invoke in the SOAP Webservice .
Below code can be used :

```
ADUserProdAuthMainServiceLocator loc=new ADUserProdAuthMainServiceLocator();
Employee result=loc.getADUserProdAuthMain().run(username, password);
```